# Identify specific git changes to not commit

Tags: git, shell

I have a CI workflow that automatically download && commit && push several translation files (.po file extension). However the commits are including a lot of files with irrelevant header changes. For instance, see this output of `git diff -U1`:

```
diff --git a/path/to/file.po b/path/to/file.po
index 595c66fb..7ee8e56a 100644
--- a/path/to/file.po
+++ b/path/to/file.po
@@ -18,3 +18,3 @@ msgstr ""
 "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
-"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-04-07 14:12+0000\n"
+"POT-Creation-Date: 2023-04-28 14:13+0000\n"
 "PO-Revision-Date: 2021-06-29 13:04+0000\n"
```

I would like to filter and ignore files that have only changes in the content of 'POT-Creation-Date', so I can add and commit files that have real contents changes (which sure would include 'POT-Creation-Date' contents update as well).

Comment: GNU `diff` and also `git-diff` have an option called `--ignore-matching-lines` (short `-I`) which you can use to ignore certain changes. With this it should be relatively easy to verify if the only changes are in those lines.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Thanks, this indeed filter. How do you suggest I get a list of the files not having specifically that pattern? One way I see is: `for file in ${list-of-files}; do [[ "$(git diff -I'^"POT-Creation-Date:')" == "" ]] || git add ${file}; done`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` has [an option called `--ignore-matching-lines`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Iltregexgt) (short: `-I`) which should help with that.

Assuming all potential changes are already applied to the working directory and nothing has been added to the index, this should add all file that contain changes other than those in lines starting with `"POT-Creation-Date:"`:

```
git diff '-I^"POT-Creation-Date: ' --numstat | cut -f3 | xargs -r git add
```

Note that depending on the shell being used the `-I` option might have to be quoted differently. This specific command was tested in `bash` and I expect it to work on any bourne shell ancestor.

Theoretically `--name-only` should achieve the same effect as `git diff --numstat | cut -f3`, but unfortunately that option seems to ignore the `-I` switch (and literally just prints names of files that have changes).

Comment: Awesome. Just to complement that I also had to add new untracked files, and now I need to avoid the aforementioned ignored files. So after your suggested command I included `git add $(git ls-files -o --exclude-standard *.po **/*.po)`  and the untracked files were magically added along. Thanks!